# Javascript clearInterval of interval set in another scope

Tags: javascript, html

Still getting the hang of javascript and am not sure how I do this..

I am using intervals to send error and success messages on a page and have run into some issues.

Let's say I have a the following:

```
function setMyInterval(element) {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        // add some child nodes to element
        // play with the css
    }, 20);
    return timer;
}

function callMyInterval() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("element");
    var myIntervalRef;
    if(!parent.firstChild) {
        myIntervalRef = setMyInterval(parent);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myIntervalRef);
        while(parent.firstChild) {
            parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
        }
        myIntervalRef = setMyInterval(parent);
    }
}

<button onclick="callMyInterval();" >Reset</button>
```

How would I clear the interval in this case?  I have tried a few variations of above, but not successful.  I think the problem is due to myIntervalRef not having a reference to the previous call of the function, but not sure how to correct this.

Thanks to all in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, move your `myIntervalRef` outside as a globally accessible function will do. Doing so will **allow other functions to access it** and make changes to it.

```
// Moving the function reference outside of the method, so other function can access it.

var myIntervalRef;

function setMyInterval(element) {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        // add some child nodes to element
        // play with the css
    }, 20);
    return timer;
}

function callMyInterval() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("element");
    if(!parent.firstChild) {
        myIntervalRef = setMyInterval(parent);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myIntervalRef);
        while(parent.firstChild) {
            parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
        }
        myIntervalRef = setMyInterval(parent);
    }
}

<button onclick="callMyInterval();" >Reset</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!!! i caught that minutes later.  I got it figured out thanks!  One more question though, when you suggest to clear it again, is that necessary since I cleared it 4 lines above your suggestion and never called it since that clear call?

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad, didn't notice the `clearInterval()` on top. I think you can just remove the `clearInterval()` that I added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the interval variable outside of the function scope so that subsequent calls to the `callMyInterval` will refer to the same instance.

You have defined it in the local scope of the function so every call to `callMyInterval` will refer to a new variable instance so you will not get reference to the previous timer.

```
var myIntervalRef;

function callMyInterval() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("element");
  if (parent.firstChild) {
    clearInterval(myIntervalRef);
    while (parent.firstChild) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
    }
  }
  myIntervalRef = setMyInterval(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var myIntervalRef;
```

Is local variable of your function, make it global is fastest way to fix